# how to add list of class to listboxbox1 and move selected item to listbox2?

Tags: c#

I have 2 list boxes. **i want to fill id and value to listbox1 from database**. Then I      want to add selected items to **listbox2** and remove items from **listbox1**.

```
List<Plan> lstPlan = new List<Plan>();
        SqlDataReader rd = null;

        try
        {
            STS_STORE_PROC_SCHEME.GetPlanParameter objInsert = new STS_STORE_PROC_SCHEME.GetPlanParameter();
            objInsert.GetPlan_fun(ref rd, ref ds, SqlReturnType.DATASET_sts);
            //while (rd.Read())
            //{
            //    lstPlan.Add(new Plan(Convert.ToInt32(rd[0].ToString()), rd[1].ToString()));
            //}
            //for (int i = 0; i < lstPlan.Count; i++)
            //{
            //    listBox1.Items.Add(lstPlan[i].ToString());
            //    //from.Items.Remove(items[i]);
            //}
            listBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Planname";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "nvcharPlanName";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
        }
```

Its giving error

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is
>   set.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you ll need to modify the data that backs the listbox (`ds.Tables[0]`) and rebind it to the listbox like you do at the line:

```
listBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Similarly, for adding and removing from one listbox to another, simply, you can

- define two lists
- make your manipulations on these lists (add items from one another,
  remove..etc)
- set these lists as the `DataSource` s of the individual `listboxes`

**EDIT:**

Code snippet..

```
Dictionary<int, Plan> dicPlan1 = new Dictionary<int, Plan>();
dicPlan1.Add(1, new Plan());
dicPlan1.Add(2, new Plan());
dicPlan1.Add(3, new Plan());
dicPlan1.Add(4, new Plan());
listbox1.DataSource = new List<Plan>(dicPlan1.Values); //this will get you only the plans

Dictionary<int, Plan> dicPlan2 = new Dictionary<int, Plan>();
dicPlan2.Add(1, new Plan());
dicPlan2.Add(2, new Plan());
dicPlan2.Add(3, new Plan());
dicPlan2.Add(4, new Plan());
listbox2.DataSource = new List<Plan>(dicPlan2.Values); //this will get you only the plans
```

Then if you want to add from 1st collection to the 2nd collection:

```
dicPlan2.Add(dicPlan1[1]);
```

Remove from a collection using the index

```
dicPlan1.RemoveAt(0); // removes the first item!! (not this => dicPlan2.Add(1, new Plan());)
```

Simple as that.. donT forget. In order to see the updates in your listboxes, you need to set the datasource again after changing the lists.

```
listbox1.DataSource = new List<Plan>(dicPlan1.Values);
listbox2.DataSource = new List<Plan>(dicPlan2.Values);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: List<Plan> is nothing , i was trying to make a list of class having id and name

Comment: what is this Silverlight, WPF? smth else? could u put your xaml at least?

Comment: as u said List<Plan> lstPlan = new List<Plan>();
            SqlDataReader rd = null;
            
            try
            {
                STS_STORE_PROC_SCHEME.GetPlanParameter objInsert = new STS_STORE_PROC_SCHEME.GetPlanParameter();
                objInsert.GetPlan_fun(ref rd, ref ds, SqlReturnType.DATAREADER_sts);
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    lstPlan.Add(new Plan(Convert.ToInt32(rd[0].ToString()), rd[1].ToString()));
                }
                
                listBox1.DataSource = lstPlan;                
            }

Comment: @Laxminarayan updated.. I gave a Dictionary as the example. learn to use it if you donT know. And please dont forget to mark as answer/vote up ..etc.

Comment: Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.

Comment: @Laxminarayan: This is a programming Q&A, not a chatroom. And please don't edit replies/more questions into answers.